# Are middlewares the new transformers of Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

I've been listening to the [Incremental APIs lessons from Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/incremental-api-development). In these lessons, Jeff is using Laravel 4 and he creates (and refers to) Transformers to manipulate data outputs.

Are transformers the new middleware we have in Laravel 5?

Comment: @user2094178 So "transformers" should still be used like described in the Laracast Incremental APIs lessons?

Comment: In @GaurangDeshande answer below, he mentions that middlewares should be used instead of filters. Are filters considered "transformers"?

Comment: Transformers are not related in any way to middleware or filters. Filters are deprecated in Laravel 5.1, and there was no middleware in any version of Laravel 4. Transformers play a key role in APIs mostly.

Comment: super! Thanks! That answers my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middleware functionality in Laravel 4.1, was inspired by the some php project and was adopted to provide the core middleware functionality to the framework. The projects’s middleware implementation relies on the HttpKernelInterface, and introduces the convention that: by decorating an HttpKernelInterface instance, we can add as many layers as we want to the application’s request / response handling stack without modifying the actual application object.

In Laravel 5, using middlewares is the preferred way of hooking into the Http layer of the framework.Laravel 5 has its own implementation of middlewares. They should be used instead of filters. The Kernel class, now registers the application level middlewares, bootstraps the core components, builds the application’s middleware stack and handles the request by passing the current Request object down the stack.

Comment: http://www.codeheaps.com/php-programming/laravel-5-middleware-stack-decoded/ ..... More detailed explanation here